# How can I read and write unsigned chars to files with fstream in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So far I have code to read an unsigned char from ifstream:

```
ifstream in;
unsigned char temp;

in.open ("RANDOMFILE", ios::in | ios::binary);
in.read (&temp, 1);
in.close ();
```

Is this correct? I also tried to write an unsigned char to an ofstream:

```
ofstream out;
unsigned char temp;

out.open ("RANDOMFILE", ios::out | ios::binary);
out.write (&static_cast<char>(temp), 1);
out.close ();
```

But I get the following error for writing:

```
error C2102: '&' requires l-value
```

And this error for reading:

```
error C2664: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::read' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'char *'
```

It would be appreciated if someone could tell me what's wrong with my code or how I can read and write unsigned chars from fstream.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The write error** is telling you that you are taking the address of the temporary created by `static_cast`.

Instead of:

```
// Make a new char with the same value as temp
out.write (&static_cast<char>(temp), 1);
```

Use the same data already in temp:

```
// Use temp directly, interpreting it as a char
out.write (reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), 1);
```

**The read error** will also be fixed if you tell the compiler to interpret the data as a char:

```
in.read (reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `read` function always takes bytes as arguments, represented as `char` values for convenience. You can cast the pointer to these bytes around as much as you want, so

```
in.read (reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), 1);
```

will read a single byte just fine. Remember that memory is memory is memory, and the types of C++ are just an interpretation of memory. When you are reading raw bytes into raw memory (as with `read`), you should read first and then cast to the appropriate type.